# Can't connect to wifi even if toast with "Connection succesful" in Android 13

Tags: android

I try to connect my tablet to my wifi programmatically:
This is my `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val TAG = "WifiBackgroundApp"
    private val ssidToConnect = "my_modem"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WifiBackgroundTheme {
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }

        connectToWifi()
    }

    private fun connectToWifi() {
        val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
            .setSsid(ssidToConnect)
            .setWpa2Passphrase("my_password")
            .build()

        val request: NetworkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
            .build()

        val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: android.net.Network) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Network available")
            }

            override fun onLost(network: android.net.Network) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Network lost")
            }
        }

        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
    }
}
```

I see the `Network available` log. and a toaster that display that the connection succesful but the tablet is not really connected to the internet.

(I'm a beginner in Android development)

Comment: `toaster that display that the connection succesful ` No. You toast that a network is available.

Comment: I log it. but in my app I see a toast `Connection succesful`. I did not implement it, it's something built-in